# Framework for a Business Dashboard - MVC, browser accessible

Tags: javascript, highcharts, devexpress, analytics

We are attempting to create a few dashboards for one of our Businesses, fetching data directly from the SQL server. We know what kind of business logic & display we'll like to do - having already built the prototypes from SQL data exported in Excel, and now - having prototyped their wireframes as well. The dashboard will include dynamic timeline based line & bargraphs & geographical map overlays.

We are trying to identify the best platform to do it. Here are the constraints:

1. The database is SQL based
2. The frontend should be browser accessible - hence a pure desktop application is ruled out.
3. While for the first usecase, the database is MSSQL - we'll like the platform to be say PHP based (or Python etc, but not ASP.Net)
4. Prefer to have the platform giving the option to host it on our systems (since our database server may not be online, but behind a company LAN - and hence not accessible from any public server, without port opening, etc), as opposed to it being only on online SAS.

Now, we are trying to architecture pieces. One approach is to have a technology stack consisting of:

1. Database - which we can live with what we have (our data isn't large enough to require anything beyond SQL).
2. An application logic framework (preferably MVC), along with a good set of libraries for Analytic applications (eg processing time series, statistical analysis - or some glue logic for calling, say R).
3. Frontend JS / HTML libraries. For this, we have looked at GoogleCharts, HighCharts, Paper.js, Raphael, Angular.js, D3.js, and new Razorflow. We haven't yet been able to figure out the best options amongst these.

Any suggestions / comments for the JS libraries (point 3) to use? And if in PHP - suggestions for good application framework + analytics library (point 2) to use above? Or if not, another language along with a good supporting framework for this?

Another alternative we're exploring is moving to a completely UX based dashboarding - eg qlikview, Tableau, or klipfolio. kibana - on the same lines looks interesting, but seems more suited for logs & text data, not exactly our use case.

Within the Microsoft world (we are trying to avoid), devExpress seems like a complete suite - with frontend JS to the backend database integration.

Any suggestions / comments on the right platform to use?
Arvind

Answer (score 1):

I am the co-founder of RazorFlow. Are you still looking for a dashboard framework to use among the options listed? Our PHP Bindings are quite powerful allowing you to build your entire application in pure PHP and not worrying about the HTML/CSS parts of it.

Let me know if you want to discuss further by reaching out to our support email at support -at- razorflow.com

Comment: Hi @skyronic, Is razorflow still active? Can you please tell me a bit more about its status? Thanks!